# Show that the sequence {$\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}},....$} is convergent using monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

QUESTION:
Show that the sequence {$\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}},\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}},\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}},....$} is convergent and it converges to $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)$.

MY ATTEMPT:
The sequence takes the form of the recurrence $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+5}$. But neither can I show it to be monotonic increasing nor bounded. Once I have shown it to be convergent, I know how to find and show the limit. I have successfully done it too. But I cannot prove the convergence.

**ONLY HINTS** required.

**P.S.** Do not use Cauchy principle or any complicated test. I want the answer to be based on monotonicity and boundedness. For the problem belongs to that chapter only.

Comment: $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$ if and only if $a< b$

Comment: @Chinny84 How do I use this to prove monotonicity for large values of n? Induction perhaps?

Comment: Hint: If $x_0<x_1$, can you compare $x_1$ and $x_2$? Which one is greater?

Comment: @Did Your hint points to induction, I believe?

Comment: INDUCTION and again INDUCTION

Comment: @Aniket Before "pointing at" this or that, did you find the answer to the question in my comment?

Comment: @Did Yes I can find which one is greater using induction. Any other ways you know of for this proof? Induction..its good but a little lengthy and tedious..

Comment: @Aniket There is no way to use induction to show that if $x_0<x_1$ then $x_1<x_2$ (or is it $x_1>x_2$ ?) hence I really wonder if you followed the suggestion in my very first comment.

Comment: @Did I thought that it was the induction step you were referring to. If not, then I think I misunderstood you... can you be a little more specific about what you are hinting at?

Comment: To show directly convergence, assume that $a=\sqrt{5+a}$ (hence $2<a<3$) and note that, for every $n$, $$\left|x_{n+1}-a\right|=\left|\sqrt{5+x_n}-\sqrt{5+a}\right|=\frac{|x_n-a|{}{}{}}{\sqrt{5+x_n}+\sqrt{5+a}}\leqslant \frac{|x_n-a|}2.$$

Comment: @Aniket No I cannot be "a little more specific about what I was hinting at" since my first comment asks a very precise and specific question (to which you still did not answer).

Comment: @Did Fine, no need to be "a little more specific". According to your first comment, if $x_0<x_1$, then I cannot compare $x_1$ and $x_2$ unless I know what form $x_n$ has. That's basically what I understand. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31353/discussion-between-aniket-and-did).

Comment: @Aniket Yes, if $x_0<x_1$ one can compare $x_1$ and $x_2$. Of course one knows that $x_2=\sqrt{5+x_1}$ and that $x_1=\sqrt{5+x_0}$, otherwise what would we be talking about? So... finally, if $x_0<x_1$ then $x_1<x_2$ or $x_2>x_1$?

Comment: @Did Of course, we have $x_2>x_1$.

Comment: @Aniket For which reason? Once this is clarified, can you show that the same reason also shows that $x_1<x_2$ then $x_2<x_3$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

- use induction
- if $a_n \gt a_{n-1}$ what can you say about $\sqrt{5+a_n}$ compared with $\sqrt{5+a_{n-1}}$?
- if $a_n \lt 4$ for example, what can you say about $\sqrt{5+a_n}$?

Comment: First bullet is for monotonicity, right? Now for 2nd bullet, when I know that $a_n>a_{n-1}$ why do I need to prove the root part? And for 3rd bullet, how do I say that $a_n<4$....intuition?

Comment: You might want to show $a_{n+1} =\sqrt{5+a_n} \gt a_n$ as part of a proof by induction of monotonicity.  Similarly you might want to show $a_{n+1} =\sqrt{5+a_n} \lt 4$ as part of a proof by induction of boundedness.  As initial steps, you will need to show $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} \gt \sqrt{5}$ and similarly $\sqrt{5} \lt 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using functional approach? consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x+5}$, and show $f$ is increasing. This takes care of the monotonicity of $a_n$'s, and you can show $a_n < 3$ by induction.